# C# - Unity3d MQTT - ArgumentException: Library compiled without SSL support

Tags: c#, ssl, unity-game-engine, mqtt, tls1.2

folks! I have been working with Unity in order to connect a Unity application for Microsoft Hololens to a server using MQTT protocol. I found a project called [Unity3d MQTT](https://github.com/vovacooper/Unity3d_MQTT)  at Github, which appears to suit my purposes.

Then, I made a C# script in Unity called MQTTListener. It is written as follows:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UnityEngine;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;

public class MQTTListener : MonoBehaviour{
    private const int port = 8883;

    private readonly string deviceId = "<deviceId>";
    private readonly string hubAddress = "<hubAddress>";
    private readonly string password = "<sasToken>";

    private MqttClient client;
    private string username;

    public TextAsset certificate;

    void Start(){
        // Forming a certificate based on a TextAsset
        var cert = new X509Certificate();
        cert.Import(this.certificate.bytes);

        // Making a new MQTT client with the formed certificate
        this.client = new MqttClient(
            brokerHostName: this.hubAddress,
            brokerPort: MQTTListener.port,
            secure: true,
            caCert: cert
        );

        // Initializing MQTT listener events
        this.client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

        this.username = "/" + deviceId;

        // Establish a connection to the target device
        this.client.Connect(
            clientId: this.deviceId,
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        );

        var hubTopicSubscribe = "/devices/" + this.deviceId + "/messages/devicebound/#";
        this.client.Subscribe(
            new string[]{ hubTopicSubscribe },
            new byte[]{ MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE } // QoS = Quality of Service
        );
    }

    private void Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e){
        Debug.Log("Received: " + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));
    }

    void Update(){
        
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine, but then I encountered the following problem:

> ArgumentException: Library compiled without SSL support
>
> uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Init (System.String
> brokerHostName, System.Net.IPAddress brokerIpAddress, Int32
> brokerPort, Boolean secure,
> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate caCert)
>
> (at Assets/MQTT/scripts/MqttClient.cs:320)
> uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient..ctor (System.String
> brokerHostName, Int32 brokerPort, Boolean secure,
> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate caCert)
> (at Assets/MQTT/scripts/MqttClient.cs:268) MQTTListener.Start () (at
> Assets/HoloProject/Scripts/MQTTListener.cs:26)

Seems pretty straightforward, but how do actually I compile library (wherever it is) with SSL support?

Comment: A quick look seems to reveal you just need to define `SSL` when you build it.

Comment: @Bart How do I define it in C#?

Comment: Given that you work in Unity, either for each file that checks for the `SSL` directive you add a `#define SSL` at the top. Or you go to your player settings, and in the "other settings" you'll find a "Scripting defined symbols" textbox where you can add `SSL`.

Answer (score 0):

MqttClient has 6 surchages, including clientCert and sslProtocol (ex:MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_1). Btw I don't see the point of using a SAS token and the 509 certificate authentification at the same time